# Catalog of LinkedServer2 from Server1 shows databases on Server1

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, linked-server

I'm on Server1 and set up a linked server to LinkedServer2, but the catalog shows the databases on Server1!

I am sure I've done something bone-headed or am overlooking something horrendously obvious, but I need a nudge in the right direction.

- Server1: Enterprise SQL 2012
- LinkedServer2: Standard SQL 2008 R2

Answer (score 1):

Check the definition of the linked server by running:

```
SELECT s.name
    , s.product
    , s.data_source
    , s.location
    , s.catalog
FROM sys.servers s
```

Almost certainly, the linked server is connected to `server1`, which will likely be confirmed in the contents of the `data_source` column in the query above.